# Facebook Groups API: how to test the app?

Tags: facebook

Does facebook want the app to be tested on live users ?
there is no provision to test the app in developer mode. it expects the app to be installed in the group .And that's only possible with a approved live app.

Or Am I missing some thing?

All I get is permissions error , even though both publish to. groups and groups_access_member_info are provided

Comment: You need to ask specific questions, and provide examples of what you're trying to do and what's happening in order for anyone to have a chance of helping you.